# Using Python to modify print settings before printing excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to write some data into a workbook and then using

```
os.startfile(excel_path,'print')
```

to send it to the printer. However, the output that I am putting out has the potential to be slightly larger than 1 page. Is there a pythonic way to modify the settings in an excel document to always fit to page before printing?

I also would like to modify the excel document to fit each column size to its maximum length in python if that is possible.

Thank you so much for any help you can offer!

Comment: You need to attempt to write the code that does this and then others will help you get it working. A Google search led me to this page which seems to have information relevant to your question: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/page_setup.html